# How to create pagination using Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

i am starting to create an ads site, i display 36 products in a blade index with success, my problem is that 36 of the products display, the leftovers do not display, and i don't know how to display the 2nd page and 3rd and so on depending on the number of pages to display the other products.

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $categories     = Category::all();
        $annonces = Annonce::paginate(36);      
        return view('annonces.index')->with([
            'categories'     => $categories,
            'annonces'       => $annonces,
        ]);
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="row mix-grid thumbnails">
                        @foreach($annonces as $annonce)
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 mix {{ $annonce->category->slug }} cat_all">
                                <a class="thumbnail-item">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$annonce->image) }}" alt="category"  />
                                </a>
                                <div class="thumbnail-data">
                                    <h5>{{ $annonce->titre }}</h5>
                                    <p>{{ substr($annonce->description, 0, 34) }}...</p>
                                    <div class="thumbnail-info" align="center">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-trash-alt"></span></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                        </div>
                        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm pull-right">
                            <li class="disabled"><a href="">«</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>                                    
                            <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: add `{{ $annonces ->links() }}` instead of pagination list. Details : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: @xNoJustice thx for you answer but i dont know where i can add {{ $annonces ->links() }}

Comment: after `@endforeach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
@if($annonces->hasPages())
    {{ $annonces->links() }}
@endif
```

If you want custom pagination, save the following as a new blade file and add name to ->links() method as a parameter.

```
@if ($paginator->lastPage() > 1)
<ul class="pagination">
    @if(($paginator->currentPage() > 1))
        <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == 1) ? '' : '' }}">
            <a href="{{ $paginator->url(1) }}"> << </a>
        </li>
    @endif
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= $paginator->lastPage(); $i++)
        <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == $i) ? 'current' : '' }}">
            <a href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
        </li>
    @endfor
    @if(($paginator->currentPage() != $paginator->lastPage()))
        <li class="{{ ($paginator->currentPage() == 1) ? '' : '' }}">
            <a href="{{ $paginator->url($paginator->currentPage()+1) }}"> >> </a>
        </li>
    @endif
</ul>
@endif
```